# How can I get value of textbox? It returns undefined

Tags: javascript

Here is my textbox

```
<input type="text" name="allowance" id="rs1"
       class="form-control allowance1" placeholder="Allowance (Rs.)">
```

Here is my code for disable textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.allowance1').attr('readonly', true);
</script>
```

While I Change dropdown value at that time I want textbox value.

```
$(".val").change(function() // this is dropdown class name
{
    var a=$("#rs1").val();
    alert(a);
}
```

I have some value in textbox and It returns undefined.

Comment: You don't give the textbox a default value. And you don't set another value to in via dropdown selection. So how could you expect to get a value from that textfield?

Comment: Do you have the only element on your page with id `rs1`?

Comment: Please create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the code you have now. I feel like we're missing some of the HTML, as you don't mention anything with the class "val" in your HTML

Comment: I had a value in Textbox by some Ajax code. I don't set default value.

Comment: ok if you are giving it a value  by some Ajax code, can you please show it?

Comment: Yes, why is this question tagged with `ajax`? ... there is no ajax in the question.  I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your demo code for `input` didn't have a value, I added one. 
Here's a working code... and I don't see an issue with yours. Is this the expected behaviour?

You should probably check on the logic that changes the value of the input field. I have mocked it in the demo.

```js
$('.allowance1').attr('readonly', true);
$(".val").on("change", function() {
  alert($("#rs1").val())
});

$(".change-value").on("click", function() {
  $("#rs1").val(Math.random());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="options" id="" class="val">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="allowance" id="rs1" value="asdf" class="form-control allowance1" placeholder="Allowance (Rs.)">

<button class="change-value">Change Input Value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to do like this.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="allowance" id="rs1"  class="form-control allowance1" placeholder="Allowance (Rs.)">
<select class="val">
   <option value"One">One</option>
   <option value"Two">Two</option>
   <option value"Three">Three</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$( ".val" ).change(function() {
    $("#rs1").val("some text");
  alert( $("#rs1").val());
});
```

working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ka2k210f/)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Instead of get the value on `$("#rs1").on('keyup'...` you have to do this on your dropdown `change` listener. You can check my [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c8k9zkrd/)

```
$("#rs1").on('keyup', function(){
   var value = $("#rs1").val();
   alert(value);
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

Make one function and fire it onChange of Dropdown

```
function gettextvalue()
 {
    var a= $("#l").val();///l is textbox id
    alert(a);
 }
```